# Shogun Toolbox Installation Fails on Snow Leopard - liblapack issue?

Tags: python, shogun

I'm trying to install Shogun Toolbox on Snow Leopard.  Via MacPorts I get the following set of errors:

```
info:build Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
:info:build   "_drot_", referenced from:
:info:build       _dbdsqr_ in liblapack.a(dbdsqr.o)
:info:build   "_dswap_", referenced from:
:info:build       _dbdsqr_ in liblapack.a(dbdsqr.o)
:info:build       _dsteqr_ in liblapack.a(dsteqr.o)
:info:build      (maybe you meant: _ATL_dswap_xp0yp0aXbX)
:info:build   "__gfortran_concat_string", referenced from:
:info:build       _dgesvd_ in liblapack.a(dgesvd.o)
:info:build       _dormbr_ in liblapack.a(dormbr.o)
:info:build       _dormqr_ in liblapack.a(dormqr.o)
:info:build       _dormlq_ in liblapack.a(dormlq.o)
:info:build   "_dgemm_", referenced from:
```

There are more, but the commonality between them is the reference to `liblapack.a`.  I have no idea why this is failing.  I installed LAPACK hoping that it would go away, but that has not happened.

Also, despite having installed `pkg-config`, when I go to configure Shogun from source it hangs up telling me I don't have `pkg-config` installed.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was completely unrelated to lapack.  The solution was not to use MacPorts, build from source downloaded from Shogun website, then edit `PYTHONPATH` to include the shogun install directory.  *Facepalm*